# Mozilla Firefox adding gap while printing

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, printing

I try to print using `window.print()`, and it works fine on Google Chrome. However, I don't know why on Mozilla Firefox it has a gap on the left side.

Print using Google Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

Print using Mozilla Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

Is there any CSS I have to add for Mozilla?

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla sets the page size to A2 by default as it is evident from this [link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/759864). So you can fix this by setting the page size to A4 for mozilla. It looks like Mozilla treats A2 as the default size.

Comment: Thanks for comment, but i check on Mozilla Firefox print setting. page size already set to A4 as default. [image for setting](http://imgur.com/a/s1bQo).